# this.getWindow()... doesn't work

Tags: android

Why this code `this.getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER);`

doesn't show wallpaper as background?

I'm interested only in this method of setting background as wallpaper.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Point ", "1.1");
        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_lock);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or exceptions?

Comment: Please clarify what does "doesn't work" exactly mean: your code doesn't compile? The application crashes? There's no desired effect observed?

Comment: Add your code instead of the PS.

Comment: post you code here...

Comment: @bajirao-shinde Take a look. I've added my code

Comment: @tynn I've added code.Take a look.

Comment: @egor I meant that that code doesn't show wallpaper.And I've edited it.Take a look.

Comment: @vsg24 Nope,I don't have any warnings or exceptions. I've edited my question. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation to [`setFlags()`](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFlags%28int,%20int%29) makes clear to call it (or in your case `addFlags()`) before any other creating the window decortation:

> Note that some flags must be set before the window decoration is created (by the first call to `setContentView(View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)` or `getDecorView()` [...]

Since you don't know what `super.onCreate()` actually does you should call `addFlag()` even before this one first in `onCreate()`.

Alternatively you can add the flag to your theme. Just set [windowShowWallpaper](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowShowWallpaper) to true there.